# How to cut/hide projected area from bottom and top of GLControl - openTK

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk, coordinate-transformation

With the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943867/how-to-project-top-and-bottom-area-of-opengl-control), I can project an image in cylindrical shape. Can I able to remove or hide the projected area from top and bottom of image as shown in the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) fragmnts dependent on the *u* (`.y`) texture coordinate.

According to the fragment shader of the original question [How to project top and bottom area of openGL control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943867/how-to-project-top-and-bottom-area-of-opengl-control):

> ```
> precision highp float;
> uniform sampler2D sTexture;
> varying vec2 vTexCoord;
>
> void main()
> {
>      vec2  pos     = vTexCoord.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;
>      float b       = 0.3;
>      float v_scale = (1.0 + b) / (1.0 + b * sqrt(1.0 - pos.x*pos.x));
>
>      float u = asin( pos.x ) / 3.1415 + 0.5;
>      float v = (pos.y * v_scale) * 0.5 + 0.5;
>      if ( v < 0.0 || v > 1.0 )
>           discard;
>
>      vec3 texColor = texture2D( u_texture, vec2(u, v) ).rgb;
>      gl_FragColor  = vec4( texColor.rgb, 1.0 );
> }
> ```

The size has to be limited by the variable `b`:

```c
if (abs(pos.y) * (1.0 + b) > 1.0)
    discard;
```