# Projection is not working when cutting particular area from top and bottom of openGL control

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk, coordinate-transformation

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943867/how-to-project-top-and-bottom-area-of-opengl-control/53947821?noredirect=1#comment99857968_53947821) link i can apply projection on my texture. 
Now I want to cut/remove equal area from top and bottom of my glcontrol and then need to apply same projection on remain area. I have tried like below. But as shown in the image top and bottom curve is missing on projection. 
How can I bring it back in remain area?

```c
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main()
{
    float img_h_px  = 432.0; // height of the image in pixel
    float area_h_px = 39.0;  // area height in pixel

    float w = area_h_px/img_h_px;
    if (vTexCoord.y < w || vTexCoord.y > (1.0-w)){
        gl_FragColor= vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        vec2  pos     = vTexCoord.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;
        float b       = 0.5;
        float v_scale = (1.0 + b) / (1.0 + b * sqrt(1.0 - pos.x*pos.x));

        float u = asin( pos.x ) / 3.1415 + 0.5;
        float v = (pos.y * v_scale) * 0.5 + 0.5;
        if ( v < 0.0 || v > 1.0 )
            discard;

        vec3 texColor = texture2D( u_texture, vec2(u, v) ).rgb;
        gl_FragColor  = vec4( texColor.rgb, 1.0 );
    }    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of bottom and top area (sum of bottom and top area), relative to the size of the control is `2.0*area_h_px/img_h_px` = `2.0*w`.
The ration (`h_ratio`) of the control size and the "visible" area is:

```c
float w = area_h_px/img_h_px;
float h_ratio = 1.0 - 2.0*w;
```

You've to scale the y coordinate for the texture lookup by the ration of the "visible" area and the control size, this is reciprocal of `h_ratio` (`1.0/h_ratio`):

```c
float v = (pos.y * v_scale / h_ratio) * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

Final shader:

```c
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    float img_h_px  = 432.0; // height of the image in pixel
    float area_h_px = 39.0;  // area height in pixel
    float w = area_h_px/img_h_px;
    float h_ratio = 1.0 - 2.0*w;

    vec2  pos     = vTexCoord.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;
    float b       = 0.5;
    float v_scale = (1.0 + b) / (1.0 + b * sqrt(1.0 - pos.x*pos.x));

    float u = asin(pos.x) / 3.1415 + 0.5;
    float v = (pos.y * v_scale / h_ratio) * 0.5 + 0.5;

    vec3 texColor = texture2D(sTexture, vec2(u, v)).rgb;

    vec4 color = vec4(texColor.rgb, 1.0);
    if (vTexCoord.y < w || vTexCoord.y > (1.0-w))
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    else if (v < 0.0 || v > 1.0)
        discard;

    gl_FragColor = color; 
}
```

---

If you want to tint the entire area in purple, then you've to set `color`, instead of [`discard`ing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) the fragments:

```py
if (v < 0.0 || v > 1.0)
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: projection is  working fine. but when trying to cut  the curve using below code, not exactly cutting from top and bottom curve.  //****cRoP Projection****
            if(IsCutProjection==1)
            {if (abs(pos.y) * (1.0 + b) > 1.0){
            discard;}
            }

Comment: @user2431727 You've to scale by `1.0/h_ratio ` - `if (abs(pos.y)*(1.0+b)/h_ratio > 1.0) { discard; }`